# Unable to delete folder in Download Folder in Android

Tags: android, file, download, android-download-manager

I am unable to delete folder inside Downloads.

File Already created in Download/SonyLiv folder with DownloadManager

```
File sonyLivFolder =new File
 Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),SplashFileName);

// sonyLivFolder path returns - "/storage/emulated/0/Download/SonyLiv    
            if(sonyLivFolder.exists()){
                try{

                   boolean isFileDeleted= sonyLivFolder.delete();
                   if(isFileDeleted){
                       Log.d("SplashDownloadManager","FIle deleted Successfully");
                   }else{
                       Log.w("SplashDownloadManager","FIle Not Deleted"); // Always return Not deleted

                   }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

All permissions already given in manifest.xml files

Comment: Android Q? Android Q?

Comment: `"FIle Not Deleted"`? Folder not deleted?

Comment: You cannot delete non empty folders.

Comment: @blackapps why i only created that folder and inside two items are there.

Comment: @blackapps  "SonyLiv" Folder is  not deleting -"File Not Deleted" is just a print statement

Comment: @blackapps tested in android 9 , not working

Comment: As said before: if there are files in a folder you cannot delete that folder in that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213986/discussion-between-abh22ishek-and-blackapps).

Answer (score 0):

Why try catch and boolean just check if the file exists then filename.delete(): function will delete it that work for me i dont know u.

Comment: Its not deleting for me . Files and Folder  created via DownloadManger

Comment: Are u sure that u request your permissions in the app . And at the end its go in catch section or not? Or ur app works correctly  whitout any crashes?

Answer (score -1):

I found my answer . I was trying to delete folder which contains files . In order to delete folder , first folder should be empty. 
So i deleted files first inside folder . then deleted the folder. Now its working fine.

here is my updated code

```
 File sonyLivFolder =new File
                ( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),SplashFileName);

        if(sonyLivFolder.exists()){
            try{


               File [] filesList= sonyLivFolder.listFiles();

               for(int i=0;i<filesList.length;i++){
                   filesList[i].delete();
               }

               boolean isFileDeleted= sonyLivFolder.delete();
               if(isFileDeleted){
                   Log.d("SplashDownloadManager","FIle deleted Successfully");
               }else{
                   Log.w("SplashDownloadManager","FIle Not Deleted");

               }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `I found my answer . I was trying to delete folder which contains files . ` You found that? I twice told you before.